# Android SQLite syntax error causing app to crash

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I've been struggling to get a listview to populate with data from SQLite in android studio. When the user clicks a button to view a list of hotels, the listview is supposed to populate. However, I am getting the same error each time as the app crashes.

The exception:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.aids.a09application/com.example.aids.a09application.HotelsList}:
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "to": syntax error (code
>   1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO hotel
>   (hotel_id,hotel_name,phone,latitude,longitude,price,near to) VALUES
>   (1,'Curragh B&B','+35345456429',53.124905,-6.789059,'A','Mondello
>   Park');

Here is the code for the SQLHelper class:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_HOTEL = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_HOTEL + "("
            + HOTEL_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,"
            + HOTEL_NAME + " TEXT,"
            + PHONE + " TEXT," + LATITUDE + " REAL,"
            + LONGITUDE + " REAL," + PRICE + " TEXT,"
            + NEAR_TO + "TEXT" +");";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_HOTEL);
    db.execSQL(insertHotel(1,"Curragh B&B", "+35345456429", 53.124905, -6.789059, "A", "Mondello Park"));
    db.execSQL(insertHotel(2,"No. 5 Bed and Breakfast", "+353 1 708 6400", 53.130330, -6.755625, "A", "Mondello Park"));
    db.execSQL(insertHotel(3,"Maynooth Campus", "+353 85 110 0907", 53.379794, -6.595520, "A", "Mondello Park"));
    db.execSQL(insertHotel(4,"Tulloch","+353 45 531 988", 53.171297, -6.973274, "A", "Mondello Park"));
    db.execSQL(insertHotel(5,"Kilcullen Home Stay","+353 87 650 7195", 53.127930, -6.746819, "A", "Mondello Park"));
    db.execSQL(insertHotel(6,"Cherryville House B&B","+353 45 521 091", 53.155753,-6.963233, "A", "Mondello Park"));
    db.execSQL(insertHotel(7,"Athgarvan B&B","+353 45 405 950", 53.153120, -6.779494, "A", "Mondello Park"));
    db.execSQL(insertHotel(8,"Naas Court Hotel","+353 45 866 073", 53.216508, -6.664741, "A", "Mondello Park"));
    db.execSQL(insertHotel(9,"Gardeners Cottage","+353 86 817 4354", 53.371688, -6.715289, "A", "Mondello Park"));
    db.execSQL(insertHotel(10,"Bridge B&B","+353 45 881 891", 53.214835, -6.678269, "A", "Mondello Park"));

public String insertHotel(int hotelId, String hotelName, String phone, double latitude, double longitude, String price, String nearTo) {
    String insertHotelToDB = "INSERT INTO " + TABLE_HOTEL
            + " (" + HOTEL_ID + "," + HOTEL_NAME + "," + PHONE + "," + LATITUDE + "," + LONGITUDE + "," + PRICE + "," + NEAR_TO
            + ") VALUES (" + hotelId + ",'" + hotelName + "','" + phone + "'," + latitude + "," + longitude + ",'" + price + "','" + nearTo + "')" + ";";
    return insertHotelToDB;
}`
```

Here is the hotels list class:

```
public class HotelsList extends AppCompatActivity {
ListView hotelList;
//SQLHelper db = new SQLHelper(this);
List<Hotel> getAllHotels;
ArrayAdapter adapter;
SQLHelper db = new SQLHelper(this);
@Override
public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.hotel_list);
    hotelList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.hotel_listView);
    getAllHotels = db.getAllHotels();
    db.close();

    // set up ArrayList for buildingNames
    final List<String> hotelNames = new ArrayList<>();

    // loop through getAllBuilding List and add all building_name 's to buildingNames list
    for (int i = 0; i < getAllHotels.size(); i++) {
        hotelNames.add(getAllHotels.get(i).getHotelName());
        //sort alphabetically
        Collections.sort(hotelNames);

    }
    // set up adapter for searchBar listView
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(HotelsList.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, hotelNames);
    hotelList.setAdapter(adapter);
}

}
```

And here is the fragment containing the button to open the list of hotels:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_open_hotels, container, false);
    Button openHotel = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.hotelsButton);
    openHotel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intentOpenHotelPage = new Intent(getActivity(), HotelsList.class);
            startActivity(intentOpenHotelPage);
        }
    });
    return view;

}
```

Comment: remove space between `near to` set NEAR_TO ="near_to" instant of NEAR_TO ="near to"

Comment: In addition to the above comment, you need a space between the column name and the column type. `+ NEAR_TO + "TEXT" +");";`

Comment: @cdav Can u post your constants as well? looks like NEAR_TO is set as "near to"

Answer (score 1):

You should add **`SPACE`** & Remove **`;`**

**Don't**

```
+ NEAR_TO + "TEXT" +");";
```

**Do**

```
 + NEAR_TO + " TEXT" + ")";
```

Then **Uninstall** App & **RUN** .

Comment: we can't say that right because while declaring it may be like NEAR_TO = "near to ". Just  a guess

Comment: and... `Near To` needs to be named `NearTo` or `Near_To` (or `[Near To]`, to keep the space - not encouraged!)

Comment: and... the semicolon (`;`) at the end of the SQL command is useless... ;)

Comment: Well the semicolon is just unnecessary, but not harmful. You will save 2 bytes for every occurrence where you won't put it! And on systems with only 512 MB RAM, it can be a life saver... ;)

Answer (score 0):

Do this in your Query,

`+ NEAR_TO + "TEXT" + ")";`

Your Code `+ NEAR_TO + "TEXT" +");";` -wrong

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend inserting into the database slightly differently to avoid syntax related issues.  The `SQLiteDatabase` class has the capability to perform basic CRUD operations via the use of `ContentValues`.  A simple insertion example could be as follows:

```
SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

values.put(COLUMN_1, "your col 1 value here");
values.put(COLUMN_2, "your col 2 value here");
values.put(COLUMN_3, "your col 3 value here");
...

database.insert(TABLE_1, null, values);
```

By following a structure like this, you no longer need to generate queries as a string and execute them.  This will make your life easier, you'll abide by general SQLite guidelines, and make your code more readable.

Also as another tip/side note:  I noticed you basically initialize the table with some values in the onCreate() of your DB class.  When I have needed to do something similar before, I had created an initTable() function in which I followed the same pattern as described above.  However, note that the insertion must occur numerous times in the method to accomplish inserting multiple rows, so the function would end up looking something like this:

```
private void initPeople(SQLiteDatabase db){

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(FIRST_NAME, "Foo");
    values.put(LAST_NAME, "Bar");
    db.insert(TABLE_PEOPLE, null, values);

    values.put(FIRST_NAME, "John");
    values.put(LAST_NAME, "Smith");
    db.insert(TABLE_PEOPLE, null, values);
}
```